# Why will my green bar in Ingress only fill up half way?

Tags: ingress

I am playing Ingress. I have noticed that my green bar at the top will only fill up halfway. Why is that happening?

Comment: A screenshot would be helpful. If you're talking about the AP bar, it is filling up, just very slowly. If you're talking about the XM bar, then it's because you're not collecting enough XM to fill it up.

Comment: I am talking about the xm bar at the top. And as I drive if I am below fifty percent then it will fill but once I reach 50 percent it stops collecting them.

Comment: I also tried using a power cube and it would not move past 50%

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again? (Completely, not just jumping to home screen, but killing the app)

Answer (score 8):

Just figured it out! You have to [verify](https://support.google.com/ingress/answer/4552654?hl=en&ref_topic=3403241) your phone by SMS to unlock full use of the XM bar and the ability to drop items.

Answer (score 2):

XM can not be collected past some speed. The scanner just does not collect XM if your speed is too high.

Try again while walking.